# Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary error: System DML Exception error

Tags: dlrs

The system throws this error whenever a Community Cloud guest user tries to donate to our organization...see attached error.

I have multiple DLRS rollup fields that counts and sums up the donation records, which is around 4000 of them. The rollups are scheduled for a nightly calculation.

I gave read access to the Guest User profile for all the DLRS objects and upgraded to the latest release already, per a post suggestion on Github, but it still doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Wil
[image][image]

Comment: The [DLRS Trailblazer community group](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5pCAE) is the best resource for DLRS support.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.